# RabbitMQ reliability, How much reliable is RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I am new to RabbitMQ, I like to know -  "How much reliable is RabbitMQ? Can it be deployed in Mission Critical Distributed Asynchronous System?"

Comment: Consider specifying more details about the reliability use case you’re trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Our organization, and many others for that matter, is successfully using RabbitMQ in mission critical distributed systems.

The reliability mechanisms that it offers out of the box cover most of the use cases you can initially think of. You can read all about them here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html

This can also be extended through the available plugins.

RabbitMQ is also one of the most mature and established messaging solutions out there, with a great documentation and solid community.

That being said, this is a pretty broad question and prone to subjective answers.

Comment: *"this is a pretty broad question and prone to subjective answers"* - indeed, so you should vote to close it as either "needs more focus" or "opinion-based". Please see the section on "answering well-asked questions" here: [answer].